# What does (excluding voted synonyms) mean?

Tags: support, tag-management

There are some [tag synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=creator&filter=all?cb=1) that are pending. To me this means that someone created/proposed them.

But when I click on the ["suggested" filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest), I (currently) only see four entries.

Is this a bug or what hides behind the "suggested"-tooltip, saying "...(excluding voted synonyms)"?

I see 
[image]

Comment: I see 19, not seven. But maybe that's because I am a mod? (19 I think is the total count of the proposed but not yet approved synonyms.)

Comment: I'll ask a dev to check. But I suspect the "suggested" filter perhaps filters for only the ones that you can vote on? http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: @WillieWong I can't vote on mine! Ok I can suggest there, but displaying them then doesn't make any sense...

Comment: How does the voting on these work again? I couldn't find a way to do it on the linked page.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen since [you](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen?tab=tags&sort=name&page=3) have enough positive votes on answer in [tag:integration], you go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integration/synonyms) to vote on doraemonpaul's suggestion (Click on the master's link on the tag synonyms page)...

Comment: Ah! Thanks, draks. So the right to up/downvote a synonym proposal depends on one's activity related to the tag as opposed to, say, overall rep. Makes sense.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen see the link I included in my previous comment for the exact rules.

Comment: @WillieWong could it be that only tag synonyms where somebody voted on are displayed as "suggested"? Because now that somebody voted, two of them show up as "suggested". But then that's a bug, isn't it?

Comment: @WillieWong I voted on [Marc's suggestions](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/binomial-coefficients/synonyms), but it doesn't show up when I click on "suggested". Any news from the developpers?